# A basic 3 table inner join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I tried looking for a question such as this on SO but a lot of them were outer joins with more complicated select clauses whereas my question is more simple and should be a faster reference for newbies at MySQL.

Being used to Oracle SQL, I was trying to join three tables and perform a delete like so:

```
DELETE * FROM tbl_login, tbl_profile, images
WHERE tbl_login.loginid = tbl_profile.loginid
AND tbl_profile.loginid = images.loginid
AND loginid = 'derek';
```

In MySQL my attempt is:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_profile, images, tbl_login
USING tbl_profile INNER JOIN images INNER JOIN tbl_login
WHERE tbl_profile.loginid = images.loginid 
AND images.loginid = tbl_login.loginid
AND loginid='derek';
```

I ran this in the SQL section of PHPMyadmin and it told me that loginid was ambiguous which I thought was funny because if I'm joining the three tables why would it be ambiguous? So I edited it and made it

```
tbl_login.loginid = 'derek'
```

that deleted the correct row from the tbl_login table but it ended up deleting all the rows from my other tables. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query should look something like this (note the different way the join conditions are defined):

```
DELETE FROM tbl_profile, images, tbl_login
USING tbl_profile INNER JOIN images ON images.loginid = tbl_profile.loginid
INNER JOIN tbl_login ON tbl_login.loginid = tbl_profile.loginid
WHERE tbl_login.loginid='derek';
```

I assume you want to delete the rows from all 3 tables. If you only want to delete from tbl_login, the previous answer tells you how to do it :)

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to delete the rows from all 3 tables or delete 1 row after joining the 3 tables (I like to think of it that way). This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remove `tbl_profile` and `images` from your `FROM` clause.